# HTML - Bind textinput to label

Tags: javascript, php, html, textinput

Quick question;

I have a form with inputs (textarea, select, and edit), and I want to mirror what I write into these. I want to bind the data I type here to other fields, just for visual confirmation.

I'm using this to create a small internal ToDo HTML webpage, and when you add a new task, I want the inputs to be reflected on a "preview" task above the input fields.

Any way to do this? Either HTML, Javascript or PHP?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: u mean like stackoverflow editor ??

Comment: Yes. Use javascript, handle the onchange event of the controls whose contents you'd like to mirror.

Comment: Yes, actually, like this editor :)
I'm open to jQuery too. Thought I covered it in javascript ^^

Will look through the solutions posted below =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not specifically asked for jQuery solution, here is one in plain javascript:

Let's assume that you have `textarea` and `div`, and you want to copy from `textarea` to `div` in realtime (same procedure is applicable to any other element in which you can type).

Html is this:

```
<textarea name="test" onkeyup="copyData(this,'copytarget')"></textarea>
<div id="copytarget"></div>
```

Then javascript is this:

```
function copyData(el, targ) {
  document.getElementById(targ).innerHTML = el.value;
}
```

This simply copies everything typed into `textarea` every time you lift a finger off the key on your keyboard.

Comment: I'm open for jQuery too. =)
But I will try your solution here!

Comment: This won't work if the user pastes text using the context menu.

Answer (score 4):

One option, using jQuery:

```
$(':input').change(function(){
    $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text('Label for "' + this.id + '" value: ' + this.value);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/X5eLr/).

In plain JavaScript (belatedly):

```
function updateLabel (){
    var label = this.labels[0],
        textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
    label[textProp] = 'Element value: ' + this.value;
}

var inputTypeElems = document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');

[].forEach.call(inputTypeElems, function(a){
    a.addEventListener('change', updateLabel);
});
```

And to offer a  more responsive approach:

```
function updateLabel (){
    var label = this.labels[0],
        textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
    label[textProp] = 'Element value: ' + this.value;
}

var inputTypeElems = document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');

[].forEach.call(inputTypeElems, function(a){
    var evtName;
    switch (a.tagName.toLowerCase()){
        case 'input':
        case 'textarea':
            evtName = 'keyup';
            break;
        default:
            evtName = 'change';
    }
    a.addEventListener(evtName, updateLabel);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/X5eLr/3/).

References:

- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- jQuery:

  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Worth noting that this needs jquery?

Comment: @David, I do not think so you will have immediate reflection of typing with this "change" event

Comment: @Dushyant: agreed, updated to address that shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

you can simple use key up function with [jQUery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$("#textBox").keyup(function(){
   $("#message").val($(this).val());
});
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfHSS/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event on input fields.

```
$('input, texarea').change(function(){
    $('#previewFor' + $(this).attr('id')).text( $(this).val() );
});

$('select').change(function(){
    $('#previewFor' + $(this).attr('id')).text( $('option:selected', this).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

insert into you html page

```
<script>

    var inputTextHandler = function(){

      // you input 
      var MyTextInput = $("#MyTextInput");

      // set listener to yurs input
      MyTextInput.change(function(){
        // curren text of input field
        var newText = this.val();
        // set this text to prewie block
        $("#MyTextPrewie").val(newText);
      });

    }

    // run you handler
    inputTextHandler();

</script>

<input id="MyTextInput"></input>
<input id="MyTextPrewie"></input>
```